# How to manually cluster rows for heatmap

Tags: r, cluster-computing, heatmap

I am trying to make a heatmap composing of several different "clusters" of gene types. For example, 5 genes are related to protein folding, 5 genes are related to ECM composition, etc. I would like to manually "cluster" these and plot in one heatmap. All the clustering methods I have seen (hclust) don't seem to offer any manual leverage. I was wondering if anyone could offer any solutions? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use facets to show your clusters.  Eg:

Create a dataset with 25 genes each associated with one of five clusters, and five observed values for each.

```
df <- data.frame(geneName = rep(paste("Gene", 1:25), each=5),
                  cluster = rep(paste("Cluster", 1:5), each=25),
                  x = rep(1:5,25),
                  y = rnorm(125))
```

Now make your heatmap, with the `cluster` variable used as the row facets.  This gives you nice labelling of the clusters and groups the genes up nicely.

```
ggplot(df) + aes(x, y=geneName, fill=y) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  facet_grid(rows=vars(cluster), space="free", scale="free")
```

[image]